# I got a array contains integers like 737511, how do I convert every integer in that array into date like 2020-03-27

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

In python, I got an array that contains integers like 737511, it's supposed to mean 2020-03-27 (March 27th, 2020). How do I convert that integer into 2020-03-27? The left column is the array I want, the right column is the array I got.

```
2020-03-16     737502
2020-03-17     737503
2020-03-18     737504
2020-03-19     737505
2020-03-20     737506
2020-03-23     737507
2020-03-24     737508
2020-03-25     737509
2020-03-26     737510
2020-03-27     737511
```

When I do

```
timestamp = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(1585300000)
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

I got 2020-03-27 which was correct.

But when I do

```
a = 733860
timestamp = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(a*1585300000/737511)
print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

I got 2019-12-27 but I want 2010-03-27.

Comment: Why do you think that logic would work? Could you, please explain a bit more?

Comment: Are you sure about that conversion table?  Left side jumps from 03-20 to 03-23, while the right side increases by one.  The values after that point can easily be calculated by `datetime.date.fromordinal(N)`.

Comment: datetime.date.fromordinal Worked, Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use datetime.date.fromordinal()

Answer (score 0):

'737511'I believe this number is a serial value for the Gregorian calendar.

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

d = mdates.num2date(737511)

d
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 27, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.date.fromordinal(a)
```

worked

Sorry, I made a mistake, I actually want 2010-03-29 for 733860